Manga about an art kid that gets transferred to another world and uses his drawings to make a shelter and other stuff, and heal animals and friends
I remember the manga, I just can't remember the name.
It's about a kid. He has dark hair and eyes. We find out that he loves to draw and make art, but his parents don't support him and everyone thinks it's pointless for him to get into art (except one teacher who encourages him).
Suddenly, he gets transferred to another world, in a strange forest, with nothing but a pencil and sketch/notepad. (It was probably in a bag or something with other stuff but I don't remember.)
He draws an apple (I think) and it comes to life, through which he finds out about his skill. He then uses said skill to make a home, a pond (I think), furniture, some food & clothes, etc.
He also uses his skill to heal mystic creatures like unicorns/Pegasus (which made them his friends) and also uses it to heal his new human friend.
That's all I can remember and I swear it's real. I have read it. (By the way, the protagonist is a child in the entire part of what I wrote.)

This is The Mochi I Drew Is Tasty Today Too.

Tougo is a high school student who loves drawing more than anything. One day, he woke up in a deep forest filled with vegetations he had never seen before... While he went on an exploration finding answers in this new world, he found them without putting much effort. When he drew a Mochi using pencil and paper, something unusual happened...?! Not just a log house but legendary beasts too?! With ability to bring anything into being, he creates a paradise for everyone! A young boy who unbeknownst to him is loved by others.

Tougo Kamizora is a Japanese high school student who loves to draw. The only person he knows who approves of his hobby is a man he addresses as 'sensei,' who lets Tougo use a room in his house as an art room (not sure if this person is actually a teacher at his school or not).
In chapter 1, Tougo  wakes up in a forest in another world and discovers that he can now create things by drawing them.
In chapter 2, he creates an apple and a pond by drawing them. (He also creates a sketchbook, some art supplies, and a satchel to carry them in, because all he had to draw with initially were a few folded sheets of paper, a pencil, and an eraser he was carrying in his jacket pocket.)



In chapter 4, he creates a house in the forest and discovers that he can heal some injured tenma (winged horses) and unicorns by drawing them in a healthy state.



In chapter 5, he befriends a young man named Fei Blad Redgard. In chapter 7, Redgard sustains several injuries. In chapter 8, Tougo heals those injuries.

I'm so thankful, you have no idea <3
